# Slick2D Simple StateBasedGame not working

Tags: java, software-engineering, slick

I recently started trying to work with outside Java libraries like Slick2D. This is my first time doing so, so I basically have no clue what I am doing.

I tried making a simple StateBasedGame that only displays a menu bar showing three options. The problem is that in my 'Game' class, the initStatesList() method isn't being called and I don't know why not. Here's the code:

Game class

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Game extends StateBasedGame {
    public Game(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game("Text Based");
    }

    @Override
    public void initStatesList(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
        System.out.println("InitStates");
        addState(new Menu());
    }
}
```

Menu class:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Menu extends BasicGameState {

    private int ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1) throws SlickException {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("Higher or Lower", 50, 10);

        g.drawString("1. Play Game", 50, 100);
        g.drawString("2. High Scores", 50, 120);
        g.drawString("3. Quit", 50, 140);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1, int arg2) throws SlickException {

    }

    @Override
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

}
```

I have no clue why it doesn't work...

Answer (score -2):

You need to use AppGameContainer.